# Java Scanner - double error

Tags: java, double

I have problem with scanner. If I try to use double, console gives me error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>                    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>                    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>                    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
>                    at test.test.main(test.java:9)

code

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print("vlozte hmotnost: ");
    Scanner vstup = new Scanner (System.in);
    double hmotnost = vstup.nextDouble();

//------------------------------------------        

    System.out.print("vlozte drahu: ");
    Scanner vstup2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double draha = vstup2.nextDouble();

//------------------------------------------

    double sila = hmotnost * 10;

//------------------------------------------

    double praca = sila * draha;
    System.out.print("praca je: ");
    System.out.print(praca);
    System.out.println(" Joulov");
```

Comment: Well what are you entering? We can't tell what's wrong without knowing the input...

Comment: Why do you need two Scanners?

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: my input was 1.5 and my question is how to fix it

Comment: Are you reading any String input anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Well, there's something you're missing here because 1.5 should work. http://ideone.com/SHBU4K

Comment: No I tried again and it gives me error message above

Comment: You have two instances of `nextDouble` but only specified one input, what EXACTLY are you typing each time you're prompted for input?

Comment: Im typing ONLY doubles into both inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type *1,5* instead of *1.5*. Also, as mentioned above, You can use one scanner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("vlozte hmotnost: ");
        Scanner vstup = new Scanner(System.in);
        double hmotnost = vstup.nextDouble();

//------------------------------------------

        System.out.print("vlozte drahu: ");
        double draha = vstup.nextDouble();

//------------------------------------------

        double sila = hmotnost * 10;

//------------------------------------------

        double praca = sila * draha;
        System.out.print("praca je: ");
        System.out.print(praca);
        System.out.println(" Joulov");
    }
}
```

Comment: See the marked duplicate I mentioned, if you want to parse using your locale (so you can parse commas or periods specifically as decimal separators) you can use [`Scanner.useLocale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale))

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need two Scanners. A nextDouble() on first scanner would help you read the next value.

Also I don't see why you are getting errors. I tried you code and it works just fine.

Output :

```
vlozte hmotnost: 1.5
vlozte drahu: 4.5
praca je: 67.5 Joulov
```